# htacess - use optional value in url

Tags: .htaccess

I have urls like:

```
www.example.com => rewritten to www.example.com?type=default
www.example.com/foo => rewritten to www.example.com?page=foo&type=default
www.example.com/bar => rewritten to www.example.com?page=bar&type=default
```

and I want be able for users to use as well

```
www.example.com/d/ => rewritten to www.example.com?type=d
www.example.com/e/ => rewritten to www.example.com?type=e
www.example.com/d/foo => rewritten to www.example.com?page=foo&type=d
www.example.com/e/foo => rewritten to www.example.com?page=foo&type=e
www.example.com/d/bar => rewritten to www.example.com?page=bar&type=d
www.example.com/e/bar => rewritten to www.example.com?page=bar&type=e
```

Currently, for the first I am using simple RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(foo|bar)$ index.php?page=$1&type=default [QSA,L]
```

But how can I add the support for specific types?
I can do

```
RewriteRule ^(d|e)/(foo|bar)$ index.php?page=$2&type=$1[QSA,L]
```

but is there a way how to write it in a single rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for it.

> "?" Makes the match optional.

```
RewriteRule ^(d|e)/?(foo|bar)?$ index.php?page=$2&type=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Reference : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex

Comment: @MartinPerry could you tell me what exactly is not working?

Comment: Figured it out. There should be `^(d|e)?/?(foo|bar)?$ index.php?page=$2&type=$1 [QSA,L]`